# How can I hide one commerce specific shipping option without deleting?

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I am trying to hide a couple of Commerce shipping options we no longer use.

I can't figure out the proper syntax for addressing the individual form radio options.

Here is what I have so far:

`function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_shipping_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#options']['express_shipping']['#access'] = FALSE;
}`

...this throws an error ' Illegal string offset #access'. Am I addressing the wrong member of the array? I've used this code before successfully for text and select fields, but never a radio.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to remove the value from the form by using `unset($form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#options']['express_shipping']);`.

Also note that most of commerce's actions are handled by rules, there might be something there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since shipping service availability is determined by Rules, as mentioned in Neograph734's answer, you can simply add a condition that is guaranteed to be FALSE to the component for the relevant shipping services. I don't believe we'd considered "disabling" shipping services in the past, so you might consider adding that as a feature request to the module's issue queue.